# sizeof is not returning correct size of LPVOID variable

Tags: c++, visual-c++

sizeof is not returning the size of Data to which tData is Pointing
my compiler visual studio c++ 2012

```
bool FixReloc(LPVOID pModule,LPVOID tData,LPVOID pAddressNew,DWORD pAdrressOld,WORD fImageX64)
{
    DWORD iDelta = (DWORD)pAddressNew - pAdrressOld;
    long iSize =  sizeof (tData);
```

iSize was 4 but when i create tData i did that

```
byte* tData = new byte[2057];
relocRaw = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(pointerToRawData + (virtualAddressBaseReloc - virtualAddress));
```

iSize should be 2057
any solution?

Comment: A pointer on your machine is 4 bytes wide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find size of array pointed to by pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14796147/11683)

Comment: it is not possible to get sizeof buffer once we have the pointer. sizeof(LPVOID) == 4 (usually); `sizeof(*tData)` (inside FixReloc) can be 0 or 1 (not defined).

Comment: _Why_ do you think `sizeof` should behave that way? Who taught you such gibberish?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious i did'nt learn c++ i learnd it myself

Answer (score 1):

A pointer on your machine is 4 bytes wide. If you want to get the size of the object pointed to by the pointer you must dereference it:

```
long iSize = sizeof(tData);  // Gets size of pointer = 4
iSize = sizeof(*tData);      // Gets size of pointed object, which is sizeof(void), which is implementation defined
```

Unfortunately dereferencing a `void *` is not very useful to you, as its implementation defined (or undefined) and even if it is defined it would not help you get the size of the byte array.

Comment: `sizeof(*tData) == 1` because tData is `byte*` and `sizeof(byte) == 1`. It is not possible to get real data size once you have the pointer (and not the array - `byte[2057]&`)

Comment: sizeof(*tData) == 1. To get the size of the memory block that tData points to, you would either have to pass it in a separate parameter, or unravel the heap block where tData is allocated to find it.

Comment: Is there any way to get its real size without sending extra parameter of its size in func?

Comment: @user3660095: Not really, no.

Comment: @firda: `LPVOID` is a typedef for `void*` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx), so `sizeof *tData` *should* be rejected with an error message. The type `void` has no size.

Comment: @KeithThompson: the example is mixed, once it is LPVOID, the other time it is `byte*`. Some compilers may return 1 for sizeof(void), some return 0, some vould complain. Undefned.

Comment: Sometimes I use `struct {void* ptr, size_t size}` or something like it to pass pointers when the size of the block is important. Using a structure in that way helps me to keep the size associated with the pointer.

Comment: @firda: `sizeof (void)` isn't merely undefined, it's invalid; any conforming compiler must at least warn about it. (Some compilers may support it as an extension.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666224/what-is-the-size-of-void (in C `sizeof(void) == 1`, in C++ invalid, but GCC has extension for pointer arithmetic where it returns 1 again). As I already said, I have treated tData to be `byte*` because of the second piece of code (context mixed). I would not advice to count on whatever implementation of sizeof(void) and that is what I mean by undefined (can vary).

Comment: @firda: Read the answer to that question. In C, `sizeof (void)` is a constraint violation; `void` has no size. gcc has a hack that sets `sizeof (void) == 1` to support pointer arithmetic on `void*` pointers. `tData` is declared as `LPVOID`; [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) says `LPVOID` is a typedef for `void*`. In what circumstances would `tData` be of type `byte*`? (And what is `byte`?)