# sizeof someStruct->someArray[i][j] always returns 4

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging

I've [attempted] to implement a two dimensional array, for a zBuffer as follows:

```
struct Properties {
     ....
     double** zBuffer;
     ....
}
```

Here's where it's used:

```
void initializeZBuffer(Properties* props){
    //Destroy old zBuffer 2D array (if it's already been initialized)
    if (sizeof props->zBuffer[0] >= 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < props->clientRect.Height(); i++){
            delete[] props->zBuffer[i];
        }
        delete[] props->zBuffer;
    }
    //Create new zBuffer 2D array
    props->zBuffer = new double*[props->clientRect.Height()]; //zBuffer height x width
    for (int i = 0; i < props->clientRect.Height(); i++){
        props->zBuffer[i] = new double[props->clientRect.Width()];
    }
}
```

My goal is to create an array that holds a `z` value for every `x` `y` pixel on the screen.

The problem in my code is: I check to see if the array has any data in it - it shouldn't on the first iteration, but it does. For some reason, every slot holds a size of 4.

For example, when debugging at that point:

```
sizeof props->zBuffer[1]  ----->  returns 4
sizeof props->zBuffer[100]  ----->  returns 4
sizeof props->zBuffer[1000000]  ----->  returns 4
sizeof props->zBuffer[10000000000]  ----->  returns 4
```

and

```
  sizeof props->zBuffer[1][1]  ----->  returns 4
    sizeof props->zBuffer[100][100]  ----->  returns 4
    sizeof props->zBuffer[1000000][1000000]  ----->  returns 4
    sizeof props->zBuffer[10000000000][10000000]  ----->  returns 4
```

Since it has a size of 4, naturally I try to see what's in `props->zBuffer[3]` (the last slot), but I get an error that

```
ds->zBuffer[3]
CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
```

Does anyone have any clue what is going on?
I am totally baffled and frustrated :(

Comment: It's a pointer, not an array. Pointers are not arrays.

Comment: For more info, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034450/size-of-dynamically-allocated-array

Comment: You seem to think that `sizeof` tells you the runtime size of a memory allocation. It doesn't.

Comment: sizeof is computed at compile time.

Comment: Are you sure the last set don't all return `8`? They don't *have* to, but I would expect them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand.

Let's look at `sizeof(props->zBuffer[1])` for example. Firstly, `props->zBuffer[1]` is equivalent to `*(props->zBuffer + 1)`. If we add `1` to a `double**`, we still have a `double**`, and if we then dereference it, we get a `double*`. You then take the `sizeof` that. On your machine, a `double*` takes up 4 bytes. That's the object representation of a `double*` - the number of bytes required to store the address of a `double`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So how do I find the sizeof an array?

Comment: @Imray You need to store the size somewhere when you allocate the array so you can look it up later. I recommend instead using standard library container types, such as `std::vector`, rather than doing the allocation yourself.