# How to find out what the size of dynamically allocated array is(using sizeof())?

Tags: c++, arrays

how could I find out the size of dynamically allocated array?
With normal array using the method below works fine, but I can't do the same thing with dynamically allocated array. Please, have a look and thanks for your help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    //normal array
    int array[5];
    cout << sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) << endl; //this outputs the correct size

    //dynamically allocated array
    int *dArray = new int[5];
    //how to calculate and output the size here?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Here is a similar question. Or you could just use std::vector. (:][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034450/size-of-dynamically-allocated-array

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible (to get the really allocated size from a `new`) in a portable manner.

<sup>You could consider defining your own `::operator new` but I don't recommend doing this.</sup>

You should use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and learn a lot more about C++ [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compute the size of a dynamic array so you need to provide explicitly the size of the array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    //normal array

    int array[5];
    cout << sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) << endl; //this outputs the correct size

    //dynamically allocated array
    int size = 5; // array size
    int *dArray = new int[size];


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot possibly work with `sizeof`, because `sizeof` is a compile-time operator, but you are asking for a runtime value. `sizeof(dArray)` is just syntactic sugar for `sizeof(int*)`, and `sizeof(*dArray)` is just syntactic sugar for `sizeof(int)`. Both are compile-time constants.

The reason why `sizeof(array)` works is that `5` is part of `array`'s compile-time type (`int[5]`).